# Project Euler #14: Why is my TreeMap algorithm slower than brute force?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

Background: I first learned C++ and Java in school a number of years ago, but I haven't done much programming over the past 9 or so years as my previous career did not require it.

I decided to look into Project Euler to brush up on my programming and solved problem 14, which asks to find the integer between one and one million with the longest Collatz sequence. (The Collatz sequence proceeds by, given a starting number, multiplying the number by 3 and adding 1 if it's odd, or halving the number if it's even. The process continues until the number reaches 1.)

I first solved the problem using brute force, as illustrated in the code below.

```
int n;
long temp; // long is necessary since some Collatz sequences go outside scope of int
int[] n_length = new int[1000000];
    for(n = 0; n < 1000000; n++){
        temp = n + 1;
        n_length[n] = 1;
        while (temp > 1){
            n_length[n]++;
            if (temp % 2 == 0) temp = temp/2;
            else temp = 3*temp + 1;

        }
    }
int max = 0;
    int max_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        if (n_length[i] > max){
            max = n_length[i];
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number with the longest Collatz sequence is " + (max_index + 1));
```

I thought this approach would be inefficient, since it runs the algorithm significantly more often than necessary. Any number that is part of a previous number's Collatz sequence will effectively have its sequence determined already, and so you end up calculating the sequence of every single number every single time it comes up in a Collatz sequence.

I decided it would be better to store each number in a map as soon as it comes up in a Collatz sequence, so you would only have to calculate it once. To do this, I used a TreeMap, with the numbers used as keys and the associate Collatz sequence length as the value, and used a recursive function to insert each number into the map as soon as it comes up in a Collatz sequence. (See the code below.)

```
public static TreeMap<Long, Integer> tm = new TreeMap<Long, Integer>();
public static void main(String[] args) {

    tm.put((long)1, 1);
    int maxVal = 1;
    long keyWithMaxVal = 1;
    int maybeMax;
    for (long i = 2; i <= 1000000; i++){
        if(!(tm.containsKey(i))){
            maybeMax = addKey(i);
            if (maybeMax >= maxVal){
                maxVal = maybeMax;
                keyWithMaxVal = i;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number with the longest Collatz sequence is " + keyWithMaxVal + " with length " + maxVal);
}
public static int addKey(long key){

    while (!(tm.containsKey(key))){
        if (key % 2 == 0){
            tm.put(key, 1 +addKey(key/2));
        }
        else{
            tm.put(key, 1 + addKey(3*key + 1));
        }
    }
    return tm.get(key);
}
```

I used a TreeMap since it automatically sorts the keys on entry, so as I iterate through the for loop I can quickly check whether the keys have already been inserted and avoid calling the addKey method to add the keys unless I have to. I thought that this algorithm would be much, much faster.

However, when I actually ran the code, I was surprised to find that the brute force algorithm came up with the answer instantaneously, while recursive TreeMap algorithm took much longer, around 6 seconds. When I modified my programs to go up to 5 million rather than one million, the difference became even more pronounced. I added some code to each program to make sure that the second program was doing less work than the first, and indeed I determined that the addKey method was only being called once for each key, while the number of times the while loop needed to iterate in the first program was equal to the sum of the lengths of all numbers Collatz sequences (i.e. much more often than the number of method calls in the second algorithm).

So why is the first algorithm so much faster than the second? Is it because the array of primitives in the first algorithm requires fewer resources than the TreeMap of Wrapper objects in the second? Is searching the map to check if a key already exists slower than I anticipated (shouldn't it be log time?)? Are recursive methods that require large numbers of method calls inherently slower? Or is there something else I'm overlooking

Comment: *Are recursive methods that require large numbers of method calls inherently slower?* Generally: yes. Recursions are often easier to write and understand, but transforming them into a loop may boost the performance significantly. But I do not think that this is the full reason for the increase in execution time here.

Comment: This problem is best solved using dynamic programming(your second solution) however, it seems as though your recursive solution is not doing exactly what you want. Why use a tree map instead of a hash map? You could be getting constant time lookup in your map rather than log time.

Comment: Hmm... switching to HashMap improved it a bit, but it's still noticeably slower than the first program.

(I'm a bit out of practice, as I explained at the top of my question, so I may not remember certain details like HashMap having constant lookup time.)

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: familiarize yourself with JVisualVM, and profile different variations of your app:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/

Comment: Another thing to consider is that there are 2168611 entries in the map when you are done. So while you tried to calculate Collatz sequences for 1 million numbers you have actually calculated (and stored) for twice as much. (In other words the memory bloat may be the problem). But you need to profile to be sure.

Comment: Are you creating new Integer objects every time you add an element to the map? If you turned your array into Integers instead of ints would you be comparing apples toapples?

Comment: The question is not about optimizing the code, but you already create a good lookup structure in your first code: Instead of creating a separate map structure, you could use the array you build anyway as map for all numbers smaller than the one you are looking at. Also note that the array as you use it is quite useless: You use it only to determine the maximum in a separate pass, but you could easily keep track of the maximum so far in the main loop, which will requite only one integer instead of one million.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the reasons already mentioned in other answers, the primary reason for the array based implementation to be so much faster is likely due to it having a lot of benefit of **CPU caching effects**:

1. Your two separate small, tight loops will fully fit in the **L0 instruction cache** of a modern CPU (it can contain 1,536 decoded micro ops on a Sandy Bridge). Running those two sequentially is going to be much faster than a single loop with more instructions, that does not fit into that cache. Given that the second loop is very small, it is likely that its instructions have already been prefetched and decoded as micro ops, and will fit in the **Loop Block Buffer** (28 micro ops).

   [image: loop block buffer]
   <sup>source: [hardwaresecrets.com](http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/4/)</sup>
2. There is a great **locality of reference** with regard to data access. Both in your first and your second loop, where you perform sequential access. There also the prefetcher helps, because your access pattern is fully predictable.

---

Related to these two topics and more, I would like to recommend you watch this excellent "skills cast": [95% of performance is about clean representative models](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5191-martin-thompson) by [Martin Thompson](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com), that discusses these and other topics in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

This code tests how long it takes to find the longest collatz sequence for numbers between 1 and 5 million. It uses three different methods: iterative, recursive and storing results in a hash map.

The output looks like this

> ```
> iterative
> time = 2013ms
> max n: 3732423, length: 597
> number of iterations: 745438133
>
> recursive
> time = 2184ms
> max n: 3732423, length: 597
> number of iterations: 745438133
>
> with hash map
> time = 7463ms
> max n: 3732423, length: 597
> number of iterations: 15865083
> ```

So for the hash map solution the number of steps the program has to take is nearly 50 times smaller. Despite of that it is more then 3 times slower and I think the main reason for that is the fact that simple mathematical operations on numbers e.g. adding, multiplying, etc. is a lot faster than operations on hash maps.

```
import java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Collatz {
  static int iterations = 0;
  static HashMap<Long, Long> map = new HashMap<>();

  static long nextColl(long n) {
    if(n % 2 == 0) return n / 2;
    else return n * 3 + 1;
  }

  static long collatzLength(long n) {
    iterations++;
    int length = 1;
    while(n > 1) {
      iterations++;
      n = nextColl(n);
      length++;
    }
    return length;
  }

  static long collatzLengthMap(long n) {
    iterations++;
    if(n == 1) return 1;
    else return map.computeIfAbsent(n, x -> collatzLengthMap(nextColl(x)) + 1);
  }

  static long collatzLengthRec(long n) {
    iterations++;
    if(n == 1) return 1;
    else return collatzLengthRec(nextColl(n)) + 1;
  }

  static void test(String msg, LongUnaryOperator f) {
    iterations = 0;
    long max = 0, maxN = 0;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for(long i = 1; i <= 5000000; i++) {
      long length = f.applyAsLong(i);
      if(length > max) {
        max = length;
        maxN = i;
      }
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println("time = " + ((end - start)/1000000) + "ms");
    System.out.println("max n: " + maxN + ", length: " + max);
    System.out.println("number of iterations: " + iterations);
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("iterative", Collatz::collatzLength);
    test("recursive", Collatz::collatzLengthRec);
    test("with hash map", Collatz::collatzLengthMap);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting the initial capacity of the `HashMap` to something like 1.34 times more than the number of elements you expect it to hold?

Answer (score 2):

I made a few changes to your code, and it seems faster, though still not instantaneous.

Generally, I tried to get rid of unnecessary, repeated map access.

Replacing TreeMap with HashMap changes some O(log n) operations to O(1). You never actually use the sorted property of TreeMap, just its contains method.

Going backwards in the main loop reduces the number of times the `maybeMax >= maxVal` condition is true.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {
  public static HashMap<Long, Integer> tm = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    tm.put((long) 1, 1);
    int maxVal = 1;
    long keyWithMaxVal = 1;
    int maybeMax;
    for (long i = 1000000; i >= 2; i--) {
      if (!(tm.containsKey(i))) {
        maybeMax = addKey(i);
        if (maybeMax >= maxVal) {
          maxVal = maybeMax;
          keyWithMaxVal = i;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The number with the longest Collatz sequence is "
        + keyWithMaxVal + " with length " + maxVal);
  }

  public static int addKey(long key) {
    Integer boxedValue = tm.get(key);
    if (boxedValue == null) {
      if (key % 2 == 0) {
        int value = 1 + addKey(key / 2);
        tm.put(key, value);
        return value;
      } else {
        int value = 1 + addKey(3 * key + 1);
        tm.put(key, value);
        return value;
      }
    }
    return boxedValue.intValue();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that auto(un)boxing is the source of the problem. Even the [Java SE 8 Programming Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html) mentions it:

*The performance of the resulting list is likely to be poor, as it boxes or unboxes on every get or set operation. It is plenty fast enough for occasional use, but it would be folly to use it in a performance critical inner loop.*

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, you should switch to a `HashMap` rather than using a `TreeMap`, to reduce the complexity of the insertion and retrieval operations.

However, optimal use of `HashMap` depends upon setting its initial capacity. If you do not do this, once your insertions exceed the default capacity, the `HashMap` will reallocate a larger table, and your items will end up getting re-hashed into the new table. This will slow down the execution of your program.

The minimal change would be:

```
public static HashMap<Long, Integer> tm = new HashMap<Long, Integer>(1000000, 1.0);
```

> `HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)`
>   Constructs an empty `HashMap` with the specified *initial capacity* and *load factor*.
>   <sub>[Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)</sub>

Here, we state we want the `HashMap` to have the capacity of 1000000 (able to hold that many elements) with a load factor of 1.0 (insertions have to exceed 100% of capacity before rehashing takes place).

Answer (score 1):

H, I think that containtsKey is responsible for that result.

TreeMap ContainsKey is O( log(n) )

https://github.com/benblack86/java-snippets/blob/master/resources/java_collections.pdf

And according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture :

> The longest progression for any initial starting number less than 100
>   million is 63,728,127, which has 949 steps.

We will think in Collatz complexity as C.

So, in your first case you have :

O(n * C + n) = O( n*(C+1) )  = O(k*n)

And in the recursive solution:

O(n*(log(n) +  C * log(n)) ) = O( k * n * log(n))

(I'm not pretty sure about the recursive part, but I'm sure that is more than 1 because inside the recursive function you are calling again containsKey )